# How to unbind a binded button directly after starting task?

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a short question, I have bound a button to do "dothis()" if I mouseenter it with my cursor. my current problem is that, if i mouseenter the button while "dothis()" is running, it runs "dothis()" again. How can I unbind him of it's function when dothis(); starts? my idea would be to unbind it in "dothis()" it self. but will it work or is there any other better solution?
so my aim is that the button should run dothis(); and parallel get unbinded, so it cant run dothis(); again, only if i call  mainFunction(); again.

```
function mainFunction(){
    bind(button, 'mouseenter',  function() { 



                    dothis();

                }
                });
}

function dothis(){

...

}
```

thank u

Comment: I'm not seeing `bind` attached to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unbinding and rebinding, create a flag, if the flag is true do not run doThis. If its false than set the flag to true and run doThis. When doThis is complete then set the flag back to false.

```
var doThisRunning = false;
function mainFunction(){
    bind(button, 'mouseenter',  function() { 
        if(doThisRunning){
            return;
        }
        doThisRunning = true;
        dothis();
    });
}

functio doThis(){
    /* ... */

   //at the end set it back to false
   doThisRunning = false;
}
```